# Is a slice's behavior well defined after append has been called on it?

Tags: arrays, memory, go, slice

Take for example the following code:

https://play.golang.org/p/vjux0TYz0D

It seems that, depending on the type held by the slice, append will sometimes "copy" the initial slice (the one append is called upon) and other times it will leave it pointing to the same underlying array.

Is this behavior defined, assuming the code:

```
a := []type{value1}
b := append(a, value2)
```

Is there any way of knowing if after the second operation a and b are pointing to the same memory ? Can I modify a or b in such a way that I am 100% sure the other is not modified ? Can the 'a' point to a completely different memory location after append ? Should 'a' just be considered garbage with undefined behavior after append is called on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language specification says:

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array.

If you want the slice to point to a different underlying array you need to always make a copy.

Comment: So the answer to my initial question woudl be "no" ? I mean, is there a flag that I can check somewhere or another mechanism to see if another array was allocated ?

Comment: According to the specification you can check if capacity of the slice is smaller than its length before the append. I don't really see how you could do it after the append though (unless you use reflect or unsafe, then there are ways). I wouldn't bother though. Decide what behavior you want and either always copy or don't copy.

Comment: Art is correct, the only way to be sure, outside of using reflect or unsafe, is to check, _before_ the append, if `cap(a) >= len(a) + len(addition)`.  If that is true, append will not reallocate, and if it is false, it will reallocate.  However, if you have behavior that _depends_ on one or the other behavior, you're _far_ better served either using a pointer to a slice or doing the allocation yourself and using `copy()` (which is all append does anyway).